# C# Class with list and non list items

Tags: c#

How would I add data to the below class lists. Both the lists are dynamic and the dailyclockings list can be different for each item of the clockings list.
I'm currently able to add data to each list, clockings and dailyclockings but the data in dailyclockings does not pulls through to clockings[1].dailyclockings[1]. I can only see data in clockings[1].name and dailyclockings[1].clockingdate but if I display clockings[1].dailyclocking[1].clockingdate the value is null.

What I'm try to achieve is the following

```
 Clockings[1].Department = "Testing"
 Clockings[1].Name = "Fred"
 Clockings[1].DailyClockings[1].ClockingDate = "2017/11/01" 
 Clockings[1].DailyClockings[1].InClockingTime = "08:00"   
 Clockings[1].DailyClockings[1].OutClockingTime = "14:00"   
 Clockings[1].DailyClockings[2].ClockingDate = "2017/11/02"       
 Clockings[1].DailyClockings[2].InClockingTime = "08:00"   
 Clockings[1].DailyClockings[2].OutClockingTime = "14:00"   
 Clockings[1].DailyClockings[3].ClockingDate = "2017/11/03"       
 Clockings[1].DailyClockings[3].InClockingTime = "08:00"   
 Clockings[1].DailyClockings[3].OutClockingTime = "14:00" 
 Clockings[1].DailyClockings[4].ClockingDate = "2017/11/06"       
 Clockings[1].DailyClockings[4].InClockingTime = "08:00"   
 Clockings[1].DailyClockings[4].OutClockingTime = "14:00" 



  public class Clockings
    {

        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string StartTime { get; set; }
        public int NoofDaysClocked { get; set; }

        public List<DailyClocking> DailyClockings { get; set; }


    }

    public class DailyClocking
    {
        public string InClockingTime { get; set; }
        public string OutClockingTime { get; set; }
        public string ClockingDate { get; set; }
        public string DayofTheWeek { get; set; }
        public string MinInEarly { get; set; }
        public string MinOutEarly { get; set; }
    }

 public List<Clockings> clockingTime()
        {
            List<Clockings> f = new List<Clockings>() ;

            Clockings d = new Clockings();

            DailyClocking d1 = new DailyClocking();
            List<DailyClocking> d2 = new List<DailyClocking>(); 

            float noofusers =1;
            int col = 0;
            int tmpemp = 0;
            int n =0, x = 0;


            var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].LateClocking";

            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@StartDate";
            param.Value = 20170901;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();
            param1.ParameterName = "@EndDate";
            param1.Value = 20170930;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

            SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
            param2.ParameterName = "@Branch";
            param2.Value = "";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

            SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter();
            param3.ParameterName = "@department";
            param3.Value = "";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param3);

            SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter();
            param4.ParameterName = "@Nme";
            param4.Value = "Fred Smith";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param4);




            try
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                if (reader.HasRows)
                {

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (tmpemp == int.Parse( reader["mst_sq"].ToString() ) )
                        {}
                        else
                        {
                            if (noofusers >1)
                            {
                                f.Add(d);
                            }
                            col = 0;
                            noofusers = noofusers + 1;
                            tmpemp = int.Parse(reader["mst_sq"].ToString());
                            d.UserName = reader["mst_firstname"].ToString() + " " + reader["mst_lastname"].ToString();
                            d.StartTime = reader["starttime"].ToString();
                            d.Department = reader["dept_name"].ToString();
                        }
                        if (reader["dy"].Equals(System.DBNull.Value))
                        {}
                        else
                        {
                            d1.ClockingDate = reader["dy"].ToString().Substring(0, 4) + reader["dy"].ToString().Substring(5, 2) + reader["dy"].ToString().Substring(8, 2);
                            d1.MinInEarly = reader["mnearly"].ToString();
                            d1.MinInEarly = reader["mnlate"].ToString();
                            d1.InClockingTime = reader["tmeclocked"].ToString().Substring(11, 5);
                            d1.OutClockingTime = reader["earlyclocked"].ToString().Substring(11, 5);
                            d2.Add(d1);
                        }
                        col = col + 1;
                        d.NoofDaysClocked = col;





                    }
                    f.Add(new f.DailyClockings( d2));
                    f.Add(d);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // your handling code here

            }

            return (f);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse me if I'm wrong, I would comment but my reputation restricts me.

Anyway, in this part here:

```
f.Add(new f.DailyClockings( d2));
f.Add(d);
```

It looks as if you take the `Clockings list`, add the `DailyClocking list` to the list as an object, and then add the `Clockings` object to the list afterwards.

Should it perhaps be something like this? :

```
d.DailyClockings = d2;
f.Add(d);
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me solve my problem. Now I have pick up a second problem. When d2.add(d1) is executed it add the new item and over writes all the previous elements with the new values. Sorry for these question new to C#. I'm a VB coder and have done a similar thing in VB.net.

Comment: Using your previous code, I suggest trying `d2.Add(new DailyClocking(d1));` 

It could be that it's using the same reference each time, as opposed to creating a new object from those references.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big misunderstanding in your code:

```
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (tmpemp == int.Parse( reader["mst_sq"].ToString() ) )
                    {}
                    else
                    {
                        if (noofusers >1)
                        {
                            f.Add(d);
                        }
                        col = 0;
                        noofusers = noofusers + 1;
                        tmpemp = int.Parse(reader["mst_sq"].ToString());
                        d.UserName = reader["mst_firstname"].ToString() + " " + reader["mst_lastname"].ToString();
                        d.StartTime = reader["starttime"].ToString();
                        d.Department = reader["dept_name"].ToString();
                    }
                    if (reader["dy"].Equals(System.DBNull.Value))
                    {}
                    else
                    {
                        d1.ClockingDate = reader["dy"].ToString().Substring(0, 4) + reader["dy"].ToString().Substring(5, 2) + reader["dy"].ToString().Substring(8, 2);
                        d1.MinInEarly = reader["mnearly"].ToString();
                        d1.MinInEarly = reader["mnlate"].ToString();
                        d1.InClockingTime = reader["tmeclocked"].ToString().Substring(11, 5);
                        d1.OutClockingTime = reader["earlyclocked"].ToString().Substring(11, 5);
                        d2.Add(d1);
                    }
                    col = col + 1;
                    d.NoofDaysClocked = col;



                }
                f.Add(new f.DailyClockings( d2));
                f.Add(d);
```

**1)** please add logs, or exception handling. 
at:

```
   if (tmpemp == int.Parse( reader["mst_sq"].ToString() ) )
                    {}
```

Or at:

```
     if (reader["dy"].Equals(System.DBNull.Value))
            {}
```

There might be an error or db Null, so one of your lists won't get populated and you won't even know about it, which will result in **null values**.

**2)** Do not initialize objects inside your list:

```
f.Add(new f.DailyClockings( d2));
```

**You might be loosing your data in the process of instantiating a new object.**

Use it like this:

```
f.DailyClockings dailyClockingsList = new List<DailyClockings> 

  dailyClockingsList.Add(d2);
                    f.Add(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found a solution to my problem with the aid of some of the above answers. Below is the solution is used to sure if its the best method but it does work and give me the results I need.

coded the below in my controller, a view and made changes to site.css file to allow the table to be formatted. The below is called from a view where the users select the parameters to be passed to the stored procedure.

```
private List<Clockings> clockingTime(string Branch, DateTime StartDate, DateTime Enddate, string Name, String Department, string ReportType)
    {
        List<Clockings> f = new List<Clockings>();
        List<DailyClocking> d2 = new List<DailyClocking>();
        string  UserName = "", StartTime = "", BranchFromSP = "", DepartmentFromSP = ""; 
        int NoofDaysClocked = 0;

        float noofusers = 1;
        int tmpemp = 0;
        int col = 0;

        var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        if (ReportType == "ALLDOORS")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].LateClocking";
        }
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@StartDate";
        param.Value = StartDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

        SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();
        param1.ParameterName = "@EndDate";
        param1.Value = Enddate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

        SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
        param2.ParameterName = "@Branch";
        param2.Value = Branch;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
        if (Department.ToUpper()  == "NONE")
        {
            Department = "";
        }
        SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter();
        param3.ParameterName = "@department";
        param3.Value = Department;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param3);
        if (Name.ToUpper()  == "ALL")
        {
            Name = "";
        }
        SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter();
        param4.ParameterName = "@Nme";
        param4.Value = Name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param4);


        try
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            if (reader.HasRows)
            {

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (tmpemp == int.Parse(reader["mst_sq"].ToString()))
                    { }
                    else
                    {
                        if (noofusers > 1)
                        {


                            f.Add(new Clockings(
                                BranchFromSP, 
                                DepartmentFromSP,
                                UserName,
                                StartTime,
                                NoofDaysClocked,
                                d2
                                ));
                        }
                        col = 0;
                        noofusers = noofusers + 1;
                        tmpemp = int.Parse(reader["mst_sq"].ToString());
                        UserName = reader["mst_firstname"].ToString() + " " + reader["mst_lastname"].ToString();
                        StartTime = reader["starttime"].ToString();
                        DepartmentFromSP = reader["dept_name"].ToString();
                        BranchFromSP = reader["branch"].ToString();

                        d2.Clear();
                    }
                    if (reader["dy"].Equals(System.DBNull.Value))
                    { }
                    else
                    {
                        d2.Add(new DailyClocking
                        (
                            reader["dy"].ToString().Substring(0, 4) + reader["dy"].ToString().Substring(5, 2) + reader["dy"].ToString().Substring(8, 2),
                            reader["dy"].ToString(),
                            reader["mnearly"].ToString(),
                            reader["mnlate"].ToString(),
                            reader["tmeclocked"].ToString().Substring(11, 5),
                            reader["earlyclocked"].ToString().Substring(11, 5)
                        ));
                    }
                    col = col + 1;
                    NoofDaysClocked = col;


                }

                f.Add(new Clockings(
                     BranchFromSP,
                                DepartmentFromSP,
                    UserName,
                    StartTime,
                    NoofDaysClocked,
                    d2
                    ));
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // your handling code here
            ex = ex;
        }


        return (f);



<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />


<title>Clocking Report</title>
</head>
<body>
<span style="font-size:small;float:right">@Html.ActionLink("Back", "ClockingParamaters", "ManagerSection")</span>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 500px; overflow: auto;">
    <table class="table" ; style="width:@(MostDaysClock+"px");">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:70px; height:100px;padding-top:80px;">
                    Branch
                </th>
                <th style="width:150px; height:100px; padding-top:80px;">
                    Department
                </th>
                <th style="width:175px; height:100px; padding-top:80px;">
                    Name
                </th>
                <th style="width:100px; height:100px; padding-top:80px;">
                    Start Time
                </th>
                @{

                    DateTime StartDate = ViewBag.StartDate;
                    DateTime EndDate = ViewBag.EndDate;

                    for (DateTime date = StartDate; date.Date <= EndDate.Date; date = date.AddDays(1))
                    {
                        ColumnHeader[ColumnCount] = date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
                        ColumnCount++;
                        <th class="rotate" ; style="width: 100px;">
                            <div>
                                <span>

                                    @Html.DisplayFormattedData(date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))

                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </th>


                    }
                    TotalColumnCount = ColumnCount;
                }
            </tr>

        <tbody style="height: 100%; ">

            @foreach (var ClockingDisplay in Model)
            {
                ColumnCount = 0;
                StaffClockingCount = 0;
                <tr style="height:40px;">
                    <td style="width:70px;"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ClockingDisplay.Branch )</td>
                    <td style="width:150px;white-space:nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow:hidden"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ClockingDisplay.Department)</td>
                    <td style="width:175px;"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ClockingDisplay.UserName)</td>
                    <td style="width:125px;"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ClockingDisplay.StartTime)</td>
                    @do
                    {
                        if (ClockingDisplay.DailyClockings.Count   > 0)
                        {


                            if (ClockingDisplay.DailyClockings[StaffClockingCount].ClockingDate == ColumnHeader[ColumnCount])
                            {

                                if (Convert.ToInt32(ClockingDisplay.DailyClockings[StaffClockingCount].MinOutEarly) < 0)
                                {
                                    Double vl = Convert.ToInt32(ClockingDisplay.DailyClockings[StaffClockingCount].MinOutEarly) * -1;
                                 <td style="width:50px;height:40px;border:solid;border-width:1px;text-align:center; background-color:red;font-size:small  ">@Html.DisplayFormattedData(vl.ToString())</td>
                                }
                                else if (Convert.ToInt32(ClockingDisplay.DailyClockings[StaffClockingCount].MinOutEarly) == 0)
                                {
                                <td style="width:50px;height:40px;border:solid;border-width:1px;text-align:center; font-size:small  ">@Html.DisplayFormattedData(ClockingDisplay.DailyClockings[StaffClockingCount].MinOutEarly)</td>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                <td style="width:50px;height:40px;border:solid;border-width:1px;text-align:center; background-color:green;font-size:small   ">@Html.DisplayFormattedData(ClockingDisplay.DailyClockings[StaffClockingCount].MinOutEarly)</td>
                                }

                                if (Convert.ToInt32(ClockingDisplay.DailyClockings[StaffClockingCount].MinInEarly) < 0)
                                {
                                    Double vl = Convert.ToInt32(ClockingDisplay.DailyClockings[StaffClockingCount].MinInEarly) * -1;

                                <td style="width:50px;height:40px;border:solid;border-width:1px;text-align:center;background-color:green; font-size:small  ">@Html.DisplayFormattedData(vl.ToString())</td>
                                }
                                else if (Convert.ToDouble(ClockingDisplay.DailyClockings[StaffClockingCount].MinInEarly) == 0)
                                {
                                <td style="width:50px;height:40px;border:solid;border-width:1px;text-align:center;font-size:small"> @Html.DisplayFormattedData(ClockingDisplay.DailyClockings[StaffClockingCount].MinInEarly)</td>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                <td style="width:50px;height:40px;border:solid;border-width:1px;text-align:center;background-color:red; font-size:small  "> @Html.DisplayFormattedData(ClockingDisplay.DailyClockings[StaffClockingCount].MinInEarly)</td>
                                }


                                StaffClockingCount++;
                                if (StaffClockingCount > ClockingDisplay.DailyClockings.Count - 1)
                                {
                                    StaffClockingCount = ClockingDisplay.DailyClockings.Count - 1;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <td style="width:50px;height:40px;border:solid;border-width:1px;background-color:blue;"></td>
                                <td style="width:50px;height:40px;border:solid;border-width:1px;background-color:blue;"></td>
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <td style="width:50px;height:40px;border:solid;border-width:1px;background-color:blue;"></td>
                            <td style="width:50px;height:40px;border:solid;border-width:1px;background-color:blue;"></td>
                        }

                        ColumnCount++;
                    } while (ColumnCount < TotalColumnCount);
                </tr>

            }


        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```